# Unable to restore MongoDB from db_dump

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to restore MongoDB from db_dump via terminal.

```
$ mongorestore -h localhost:27017 --db aaaa_production --archive=db_dump_071118.gz --gzip

Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--archive=db_dump_071118.gz'
try 'mongorestore --help' for more information
```

Comment: What version of mongodb? Archive option is available only in 3.2 and later versions.

Comment: @StefanR thank you. Update the version from 2.6 to 3.4. But now

$ mongorestore -h localhost:27017 --db heymojo_production --archive=db_dump_071118.gz --gzip

2018-07-14T08:34:41.121+0000 Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhary, Make sure MongoDB running on the address localhost:27017

Answer (score 1):

Before running mongorestore command make sure that MongoDB is running on the same port as specified in mongorestore command. In your case, MongoDB should be running on localhost:27017.Then run following command to restore database:

```
$ mongorestore -h localhost:27017 --db aaaa_production --gzip --archive=db_dump_071118.gz
```